# 503 error while inserting data to google big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming

Seeing the `503` error in the below code , we are sending a batch of **500** records and we will see this error if we have 50k records.

```
insertTableRequest.setRows(listOfRows);

                insertTableResponse = bigquery.tabledata()
                        .insertAll(projectId, datasetId, tableToCreate, insertTableRequest).execute();
```

For all such bigger files we see the below error:

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable { "code" : 503, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.", "status" : "UNAVAILABLE" }

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is the desired behavior? What do you want to achieve?  Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When getting a "[backend error](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#backendError)" while a jobs.insert() calls as mentioned in the error message retrying may resolve the issue.

Implementing a [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#exp-backoff) can help prevent this kind of errors.